# How to use custom serialization WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

Has any one ever implemented a custom serializer in WCF ? The reason i want to replace the WCF default serializer with custom serializer is to call different services from the same wcf proxy client.I would be glad if some one can suggest a way to do this ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Give a simplified example of what you are trying to solve. Show the problem and how you might want to solve it.

Comment: Bronumski I want to call some webservices using a single wcf client.So for each service call ,i don't want to create a service reference independently.Instead I want to have a generic client which would make calls to the services based on the configurations provided from a config file.

Comment: And how does that effect the serialization? Are the endpoints that different? Do you have to use a single proxy that you switch or can you use multiple proxies that use the same interface but different configurations?

Comment: Since I am calling the services using the same WCF client.So the endpoint,binding,contract,namespace information is different for each service.I have to use a single proxy that i have to switch on the fly.So if i use the same wcf client which by default uses the datacontractserialization which would not allow me to change any thign on the fly.Instead i want to use a custom binding where i override the WCF default behavior.

Comment: Sorry without seeing an example in pseudo code it is hard to fully understand so excuse my ignorance. You should not have to reuse the WCF client you can create them on the fly using a channel factory. In fact you should throw the client away when you are finished with it. If this is plausible I will try and answer the question properly with an example.

Comment: Inorder to use a channel factory don't you think you should have prior information of the service contract ??In my case I am not sure if I will have that information already.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar on a project I recently did.

However I did have 2 different WCF clients. How I "switched" was I then created a shared interface between the clients and then used a `ServiceLocator` to fetch the `IClient`.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I am looking for similar solution but did u try extending that  solution to more than 2 services ?

Comment: No I did not, however I do not see why the amount would make a difference. Each client had its own config, bindings etc. I then just "fetched" the client I wanted. How many services do you have which would share the same methods? The only reason I had 2 was because I had a test and live services and wanted to ensure the "live" service worked the same as the test environment

Comment: I might have 1 to n services which i would like to call on the fly reusing the same client by passing the following parameters address,binding,contract,namespace.So there might be many services which i want to call on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you have an application that you want to talk to one of two services that use the same interface based on some criteria. The services have different configurations so you cannot reuse the same config.

To tackle this I would setup the two configurations in the application config, it could also be done in code if you wish.

```xml
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://service1"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="Service1Binding"
            behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior"
            contract="IServiceInterface, Service"
            name="Service1"/>

  <endpoint address="http://service2"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="Service2Binding"
            behaviorConfiguration="Service2Behavior"
            contract="IServiceInterface, Service"
            name="Service2"/>
</client>
```

In your code you then need some sort of conditional statement to determine which service you want to talk to. Once you have done this you can create a [`ChannelFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) for the required configuration.

```
string serviceName = FullMoon ? "Service1" : "Service2";

var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceInterface>(serviceName);

var proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

proxy.SomeServiceCall();

channelFactory.Close();
```

If you are using IoC to inject the proxy you will probably need to push this into some sort of factory. You can also look at optimizing this as creating the ChannelFactory is the expensive part, it is possible to create the Factory without specifying the configuration just the contract. You would then need to specify the binding and the endpoint when you create the channel.